# How to get the id of a head

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to give the nearest player a SCP-049 head but i don't know how to put it on them, and how to even give them the head. is there a way to find the id of the head so its easier for me? this is all in Minecraft java 1.12.2

NOTE: SCP-049 looks like a plague doctor.

Comment: yay a answer actually worked

Comment: wait how do i give the player the head already on the head slot...

Comment: nvm i got it this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1.12-

### Command

```
/give @p minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"_plague_doctor__"}
```

### Put On Head

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.head minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"_plague_doctor__"}
```

Comment: Why the data value 3?

Comment: that gave me the head of a dog looking player

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 idk I just copied it from namemc

Comment: and yet it still did not work. it gave me the head of a dog and not a plague doctor.

Comment: @anomanous try new one

Comment: it worked... FINALLY

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command:

```
/give @p minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"SCP-049 (The Doctor)"}
```

Comment: but i dont know the skull owner

Comment: you want SCP-049 head right? So that should be the skullowner

Comment: i got the head from Head Database plugin on another server

Comment: Ok, then you will need to put that same plugin on your server before you can get the head.

Comment: i have the head using saved toolbars

Comment: Does the head say its SCP-049's head?

Comment: it says: "SCP-049 (The Doctor)" in blue text

Comment: Ok then use that as the skullowner.

Comment: that did not work

Comment: Just edited my answer, that should fix your problem

Comment: And make sure to put the id in between the quotes after "Skullowner:"

Comment: sooooo is it actually possible?

Comment: @anomanous Yes. See the other answer.

Comment: gave a head but not the one i need, instead it gave me the head of a dog looking player

Comment: so uh i need another answer...

Comment: also still did not work.

Comment: that gave me the head of alex

Comment: FINALLY THIS ONE ACTUALLY WORKS! YES!